# Detect MSVC using preprocessor without detecting clang-cl, icl,

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c-preprocessor

MSVC 2019 has added a new `_udiv128()` intrinsic ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/udiv128?view=vs-2019)) 
 that I would like to use in my C++ code. However that intrinsic is currently not available in both clang-cl 9.0.0 and the Intel C++ compiler 2019 even though these compilers set `_MSC_VER=1920` just like MSVC 2019.

Because of this issue the code below does not compile using both clang-cl and icl:

```
#include <immintrin.h>

#if _MSC_VER >= 1920
    uint64_t res = _udiv128(a, b, c, &d);
#endif
```

Is there a way to detect MSVC using the preprocessor without detecting clang-cl, icl, ... I would like to avoid checking for `_MSC_VER` and then excluding all other C/C++ Windows compilers.

Ideally I would like to detect MSVC using a Microsoft specific macro that is only defined for MSVC but not for clang-cl, icl...

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev the OP did say "*I would like to avoid checking for _MSC_VER and then excluding all other C/C++ Windows compilers*"

Comment: Six words: SFINAE.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to use SFINALE to make it work...

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for the Intel compiler.

Clang-cl defines `_MSC_VER` because it's trying to be a drop-in replacement for the MSVC compiler and to use the MS libraries that come with the compiler (e.g., the C RTL and the C++ Standard Library).  Those library implementations depend on `_MSC_VER`, so clang-cl doesn't really have an option.

Options:

1. Seva's proposal from the comments will work for you.  I understand is not your preferred solution, but it is an option.  You could test it in one place so that you only have to update one place when the situation improves.
2. Try using the `-fms-compatibility-version` clang-cl flag to choose an older version.  (If you don't provide this flag, clang-cl tries to discover you MSVC installation and then matches the compatibility flag to that installations libraries, which is probably why you're seeing exactly 1920.)  This will prevent your `#if _MSC_VER >= 1920` from triggering, but it could have side-effects if there are parts of the system libraries that require 1920-or-better.
3. Wait for clang-cl to implement `_udiv128()`.  Better yet, propose a patch to get it done sooner.

Comment: Sending a patch would be an option but then there is also Intel's compiler that does not support _udiv128() and I guess some other obscure C++ compilers don't support it either...